# How to find minimum and maximum among a list of integers in Python without using built-in functions from console

Tags: python, io, minmax

In the following code, I am unable to accept the input list values from console.

```
    s=[]
for i in range(10):
    s[i]=int(input('enter integers from 1 to 10\n'))


mini=11
for temp in s:
    if mini>temp:
            mini=temp
print('minimum : '+str(mini))

maxi=0
for temp in s :
    if maxi<temp:
        maxi=temp
print('maximum :'+str(maxi))
```

IndexError : list argument index out of range.

Cant find where index went out of range.Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the title (a homework?). It is ok to ask about specific issues with your code and you should *mention the context* but *don't put it in the title*. You could change the title: "IndexError while reading a list of integers". Provide only relevant parts of the code (drop everything after the error line); include the *full* traceback. Please, limit your questions to one issue per question (you could include links to related questions for context).

Comment: I am a novice programmer in Python.its not  homework, but making trail and error method for learning to code sir, I will make a note of your points definitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be `appending`, you cannot index an empty list so `s[i]` will fail straight away with `s[0]` as the list is empty:

```
s = []
for i in range(10):
   s.append(int(input('enter integers from 1 to 10\n')))

mini,maxi = 0, 11
for temp in s:
    if temp < mini:
        mini = temp
    if temp > maxi:
        maxi = temp
print('minimum : '+str(mini))
print('maximum :'+str(maxi))
```

You can also check the two in a single loop as above instead of doing two iterations over `s`.

You can also use a list compt to create your list of numbers:

```
s = [int(input('enter integers from 1 to 10\n')) for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: list compt seems a very simple way of doing the job.Thanks

Comment: @VikranthInti, yep, just be aware that the code would break for any bad input from the user, in the real world you would validate the input from the user

Comment: ok, I am novice in coding..so these might seem silly questions, but I am learning .ty

Comment: No worries, I figured that.

Answer (score 1):

you should append to the list.

```
s=[]
for i in range(10):
    s.append(int(input('enter integers from 1 to 10\n')))


mini=11
for temp in s:
    if mini>temp:
        mini=temp
print('minimum : '+str(mini))

maxi=0
for temp in s :
    if maxi<temp:
        maxi=temp
print('maximum :'+str(maxi))
```